# Triggering Jenkins pipeline on any branch in bitbucket that had code pushed to it

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

I have two repos (not my choice) for a project. The structure looks like this:

```
repo1
 |_folder
 |_tests
 |_src (repo2)
    |_index.html
    |_.git

 |_composer.json
 |_.git
```

I set up a Jenkins pipeline that will clone `repo1`, then clone `repo2` under `src/`, and finally will run `composer install` under `repo1`. The pipeline script for the `src` repo looks like this:

```
checkout([
        $class: 'GitSCM', 
        branches: [[name: '**']], 
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
        extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
        relativeTargetDir: 'src']], 
        submoduleCfg: [], 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[
            credentialsId: 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX', 
            url: 'https://BITBUCKETURL'
        ]]
    ])
```

I also have under "Build Triggers" the checkbox "Build when a change is pushed to Bitbucket" (using the bitbucket plugin). On top of that I have set up my webhook to send a request to jenkins. It should be noted that my webhook works for a freestyle project limited to a specific branch.

What I want to be able to do now, is only test the branch that was pushed to, instead of every branch on trigger. Also, we don't have a naming convention for branches, so they can be named anything that isn't `master`. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

in my project Im using this and it is working as it should (I do not really remember already why we decided this way, but there was issue either with BB plugin either with Push hooks, so we are using simple scheduler):

```

```
checkout([
                $class                           : 'GitSCM',
                branches                         : [[name: '**']],
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                extensions                       : [[$class: 'CheckoutOption', timeout: 2]],
                submoduleCfg                     : [],
                userRemoteConfigs                : [
                        [
                                credentialsId: 'CREDTS',
                                url          : 'URL'
                        ]
                ]
        ])
```

```

if I compare this with your code snippet, they are mostly same , apart from extensions. Plus it the job itself we have configured Poll Scm build trigger with `* * * * *` - check every minute